# How to code Pytorch to fit a different polynomal to every column/row in an image?

Tags: pytorch, linear-regression, least-squares

Fitting a single polynomial to a bunch of data is pretty easy in Pytorch using an `nn.Linear` layer. I've included a trivial example at the end of this post. But suppose I have tons of data split into groups, and I want to fit a different polynomial to each group. As an example, find the particular quadratic coefficients that fit each column in this image:

[image]

In other words, I want to simultaneously find the coefficients for *N* polynomials of order *n*, given *m* data per set to be fit:

[image]

In the image above, there are *m*=80 points per dataset, and *N*=100 sets to fit.
This perfectly lends itself to tensor manipulation and Pytorch on a gpu should make this blindingly fast by fitting all *N* at once. Problem is, I'm having a terrible brain fart, and haven't been able to wrap my head around the right layer configuration. Basically I need *N* `nn.Linear` layers, each operating on its own dataset. If this were convolution, I'd use a depthwise layer...

Example network to fit one polynomial where `X` are the `m x p` abscissa data, `y` are the `m` ordinate data, and we want to find the `p` coefficients.

```
class polyfit(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n=2):
        super(polyfit, self).__init__()
        self.poly = torch.nn.Linear(n,1,bias=False,)
    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.shape,self.poly)
        return self.poly(x)
    
model = polyfit(n)
loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
for epoch in range(100): # or however I want to run the loops
    output = model(X)
    mse = loss(output, y)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    mse.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after thinking about my Depthwise Convolution comment. A `Conv1D` with just 3 parameters times a tensor with values `[1,x,x**2]` is a quadratic, same as with a `Linear` layer with `n=3`. So the layer needs to be:

```
 self.poly = torch.nn.Conv1d(N,N,n+1,bias=False,groups=N)
```

Just have to make sure the `X,y` tensors are the right dimensions of `[m, N, n]` and `[m, N, 1]` respectively.